# hiding bottom navigation view when open slide menu

Tags: java, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I have a `bottom navigation view` in my project with 2 `fragments` and every fragment has a `slide menu` (`navigation view`) and I want to hide the `bottom navigation view` when any of my menus is showing,can someone give me an example how to do that?and if there is a similar question, I would be glad if you would show me it, because I have not found anything similar

Comment: You may want to read [ask]. Your question is unclear to me, but you could [edit] it and add a [mcve], that would certainly help. Requests for examples are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:menu="@menu/buttom_nav_menu"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

you will not need to hide the `bottom navigation view` because the slide menu is in front of it